# jQuery append calling twice

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append a note to a `<dd>` tag in my page, but for some reason, it's happening twice.  Here's the `<dd>` tag i'm trying to append to:

```
<dd>
    <input type="hidden" value="Choose a Country" class="FormFieldChoosePrefix">
    <input type="hidden" value="11" class="FormFieldId">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" class="FormFieldFormId">
    <input type="hidden" value="singleselect" class="FormFieldType">
    <input type="hidden" value="Country" class="FormFieldPrivateId">
        <select size="1" name="FormField[2][11]" id="FormField_11" style="" class="Field200 FormField">
            <option value="">Choose a Country</option>blah blah</select>
-- want code to be added here --
</dd>
```

I have tried using the following:

`$('dd:contains("Choose a Country").append('whatever');`

`$('#FormField_11').parent().append('whatever');`

`$('#FormField_11').parent().first().append('whatever');`

and even

```
if ($('#FormField_11').parent().html().indexOf('whatever') == -1){
    $('#FormField_11').parent().append('whatever');
}
```

all to no avail - every time, 'whatever' is showing up twice.  The weirdest part is, however, that i do the same thing for another `<dd>` tag later on in the page, and it works perfectly:

```
<dd>
    <input type="hidden" value="Choose a Country" class="FormFieldChoosePrefix">
    <input type="hidden" value="21" class="FormFieldId">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" class="FormFieldFormId">
    <input type="hidden" value="singleselect" class="FormFieldType">
    <input type="hidden" value="Country" class="FormFieldPrivateId">
    <select size="1" name="FormField[3][21]" id="FormField_21" style="" class="Field200 FormField">
            <option value="">Choose a Country</option>
            blah blah
        </select>
</dd>
```

and my javascript, which works:

`$('#FormField_21').parent().append('whatever');`

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, you want to append to `<select>` or to `<dd>`?

Comment: check the resulting source code and make sure there is only one #FormField_11

Comment: I want to append to `<dd>` - so i want the text to be just before `</dd>`

Comment: Yeah, there's only one of those IDs

Comment: For others coming here with a twice/double append: You may have something like an unclosed or badly closed tag `.append($('<input><input>))` instead of `.append($('<input></input>))`, this will add two unclosed inputs...

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Brilliant this should get a badge because im a fairly new programmer and util i came to this post i was puzzled as to why i continued to have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `.append()` is evaluating on top of `$('#FormField_11')` and not of `.parent()`.

This is how jQuery works.

To do what you are wanting, you for example could do:

```
var x = $('#FormField_11').parent();
x.append('whatever');
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error. Copying your HTML code, loading jQuery.js, and doing: `$('#FormField_11').parent().append('<a href="/pages/Contact-Us.html">Please email or contact us for international orders. Thank you</a>')`, I got just what you want. Could you share more HTML? Maybe you are getting more elements in your selection instead of just 1 `dd`.

Comment: The `<dd>` tag starts on line 62, and my doubly-appended text is on line 65. http://pastebin.com/Cwq6F08Y
And here's the JS i added: http://pastebin.com/5i2imitm

Comment: @Meltz, I can just think on old version of jQuery for this. I loaded your html removing the `<a../>` you want (http://pastebin.com/eh8Ecd8p), and loaded the latest jQuery version (http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js), and did `$('#FormField_11').parent().append('<a href="/pages/Contact-Us.html">Please email or contact us for international orders. Thank you</a>')`, and got just 1 `<a/>` inserted. Could you check?

Comment: Another thing I can think is that another javascript code in your page is calling the function that is adding this `<a />` again. Maybe you put this code in your $.ready()... and then another script is calling the `.ready` function again (in another words, calling twice the code that is adding the `<a>` tag).

Comment: Still showed up twice.  I loaded the latest version from jquery.com and google code, same result.  I also just checked in on a couple different computers to see if it was just me...it still happens.  If you want to see for yourself, just go to www.window-cleaning-supply.com and put something in your cart, then check out as a guest.  The link will show up twice under "billing details", but only once for "shipping details"

Comment: Man, are you kidding me? You have the same code on line 853 and line 1347 of `checkout.php` ... delete one of them dude... ¬¬.

Comment: Oh...jeez.  Yeah that seemed to be it, although the way this store is put together and the way i have access to editing pages, I have no choice but for it to be loaded on the page twice.  (I basically edit a template file that the site re-uses for both billing and shipping addresses.  If i put the script anywhere else, it doesn't work).  I just decided to  put the link somewhere else

Comment: this made me realise that I had multiple objects having the same class structure in my code resulting in an element created twice. so thanks for clearing that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you give an ID to the dd element, and then just append as such:

```
 <dd id="dd1">
     .....

 $("#dd1").append("content");
```

You can add the text after the last element (assuming it always has the same ID) as such:

```
 $('#FormField_21').after('<a href="/pages/Contact-Us.html">Please email or contact us for international orders. Thank you</a>');
```

Comment: Are you trying to add an extra option to the select, or just extra text at the end of the dd?

Comment: No, it's just `<a href="/pages/Contact-Us.html">Please email or contact us for international orders.  Thank you</a>` that i'm trying to add.  And I cant directly edit that particular html because it's being generated by some script file to which i do not have access (part of a shopping cart service)